# Compatibility regexp_replace() postgres and h2

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, h2, spring-test

We have Spring Boot Application, and native sql in Postgres

```
Select .... 
where regexp_replace(LOWER(company_name), '\s', '', 'g') = regexp_replace(LOWER(:suspect), '\s', '', 'g')
```

And have tests H2 databases, where `regexp_replace flag 'g'` not supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure that you need the `g` flag in the case of H2, because global replacement of all matches appears to be the default.  From the [documentation](http://www.h2database.com/html/functions.html#regexp_replace):

> Replaces each substring that matches a regular expression. For details, see the Java String.replaceAll() method. If any parameter is null (except optional flagsString parameter), the result is null.

I am assuming that H2's `REGEXP_REPLACE` is being implemented under the hood by Java `String#replaceAll`.  In this case, all matching substrings will automatically be replaced.

Regarding your problem with two different databases, you really should try to use the same database for both testing and production.  That failing, you might want to stick to ANSI SQL if possible.

Comment: But they can't remove the `'g'` parameter. It would make the tests succeed, but fail in production (as Postgres would only replace the first occurance). Another good example why it's not such a good idea to use a different DBMS for test and production

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I missed that part.  Of course, if not using ANSI SQL then there is no guarantee that any code would port to another database.

Comment: yes, I readed documenatation h2 and postgress, maybe real replace sql in spring tests?

Comment: The problem with this is that now you are maintaining two different database codebases.  It would be better to use the same database everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Note, if you want to add a missing function to H2, that you have in some other DB, you can do like so. Note that isn't the `regexp_replace` mentioned in this example, but a similar approach for `regexp_match`

Here's [more info on how to include SQL like this](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql) and [more info on H2 User Defined functions](https://h2database.com/html/features.html#user_defined_functions)

```
# H2 DB - create regexp_match rough equivalent to Postgres
# note this does not do the true match
#
# include this in a file like so:
# src/test/resources/data.sql
CREATE ALIAS regexp_match AS '
    String getRegexpMatch(String input, String regex) {
       if (input == null){
        return null;
       };
       if (input.matches(regex)){
         return input;
       }
       return null;
    }
';
```

Comment: Oh, the best solution form me, this is using testContainers. With postgress inside